# how to display fan speeds

Tags: fan

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 with an Asus Prime Z370-A MB

lm-sensors does not show fan speeds, and the Asus AI Fan Xpert program only works on Windows.

Is there a program that would run on my machine that would display the CPU PWM fan speed? I don't need to modify the speed, I just want to know what it is at any given moment.

Comment: what does your `/etc/modules` look like?

Comment: sensors-detect added 
coretemp
nct6775

Comment: I discovered that I can see fan speeds if I boot with acpi=off, but the problem with that is that I then can't see activity in all 12 threads - gkrellm only displays the 6 cores. What I'd like is to see all the threads and the fan speeds.

Comment: Try it with your grub option set to `acpi_enforce_resources=lax`

Comment: Brilliant. That works fine. Thank you very much

Comment: I'll put that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it with your grub option set to `acpi_enforce_resources=lax`

From the documentation:

```
acpi_enforce_resources= [ACPI]
        { strict | lax | no }
        Check for resource conflicts between native drivers
        and ACPI OperationRegions (SystemIO and SystemMemory
        only). IO ports and memory declared in ACPI might be
        used by the ACPI subsystem in arbitrary AML code and
        can interfere with legacy drivers.
        strict (default): access to resources claimed by ACPI
        is denied; legacy drivers trying to access reserved
        resources will fail to bind to device using them.
        lax: access to resources claimed by ACPI is allowed;
        legacy drivers trying to access reserved resources
        will bind successfully but a warning message is logged.
        no: ACPI OperationRegions are not marked as reserved,
        no further checks are performed.
```

1. Edit `/etc/default/grub` and insert `acpi_enforce_resources=lax` into the parameter string of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`, IE:
   `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX='acpi_enforce_resources=lax'`
2. Run `update-grub` and reboot.

Comment: Could you update this post with info on how to implement it as in where to post this line? I'm having the same problem that I got a CPU fan that is detected under Windows but not by lm-sensors. Thanks!

Comment: @H3R3T1K Updated.  This is usually the solution needed for Nuvoton thermal sensors on many desktops.  `sensors-detect` usually tells you what chip it finds when you run it.  Post a new question with the `fan` if this doesnt help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `Psensor` from the Ubuntu software store.

Described here:
[Psensor - A Graphical Hardware Temperature Monitoring Tool for Linux](https://www.tecmint.com/psensor-monitors-hardware-temperature-in-linux/)

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that. No fan speed showing. Same with gkrellm.