# Need to get more info on my sensors, fan speed etc

Tags: 20.04, ubuntu-mate, fan, sensors

I had sensors working in 18.04 but having difficulties with 20.04

I installed sensors and ran sensors-detect selecting the default choices.

I would appreciate the opportunity to learn what I need to do next.

Thanks.

```
sensors
k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:         +2.1°C  (high = +70.0°C)
                       (crit = +80.0°C, hyst = +79.0°C)

radeon-pci-0008
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:         +2.0°C  (crit = +120.0°C, hyst = +90.0°C)

fam15h_power-pci-00c4
Adapter: PCI adapter
power1:           N/A  (crit =  65.19 W)
```

And my hardware info. Not sure if you need other info.

```
sudo dmidecode | more

Base Board Information (Mother board)
    Manufacturer: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
    Product Name: F2A68HM-H

BIOS Information
        Vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
        Version: FB
        Release Date: 04/22/2015

AMD A8-7600 Radeon R7, 10 Computer Cores 4C+6G x 4
```

Trying some other things suggested by some members:

```
 E: Package 'hddtemp' has no installation candidate
```

I tried this to install hddtemp.

I tried this

> sudo apt update wget
> http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/h/hddtemp/hddtemp_0.3-beta15-53_amd64.deb
> sudo apt install ./hddtemp_0.3-beta15-53_amd64.deb and got Download is
> performed unsandboxed as root as file
> '/home/andy/hddtemp_0.3-beta15-53_amd64.deb' couldn't be accessed by
> user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)

I ran sensors-detect.

```
Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to
standard I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe.
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no): 
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x2e/0x2f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      Yes
Found `ITE IT8620E Super IO Sensors'                        Success!
    (address 0x228, driver `it87')
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x4e/0x4f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      No

Some systems (mainly servers) implement IPMI, a set of common interfaces
through which system health data may be retrieved, amongst other things.
We first try to get the information from SMBIOS. If we don't find it
there, we have to read from arbitrary I/O ports to probe for such
interfaces. This is normally safe. Do you want to scan for IPMI
interfaces? (YES/no): 
Probing for `IPMI BMC KCS' at 0xca0...                      No
Probing for `IPMI BMC SMIC' at 0xca8...                     No

Some hardware monitoring chips are accessible through the ISA I/O ports.
We have to write to arbitrary I/O ports to probe them. This is usually
safe though. Yes, you do have ISA I/O ports even if you do not have any
ISA slots! Do you want to scan the ISA I/O ports? (yes/NO): 

Lastly, we can probe the I2C/SMBus adapters for connected hardware
monitoring devices. This is the most risky part, and while it works
reasonably well on most systems, it has been reported to cause trouble
on some systems.
Do you want to probe the I2C/SMBus adapters now? (YES/no): 
Using driver `i2c-piix4' for device 0000:00:14.0: AMD Hudson-2 SMBus

Next adapter: SMBus PIIX4 adapter port 0 at 0b00 (i2c-0)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: SMBus PIIX4 adapter port 2 at 0b00 (i2c-1)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: SMBus PIIX4 adapter port 3 at 0b00 (i2c-2)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: SMBus PIIX4 adapter port 4 at 0b00 (i2c-3)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: SMBus PIIX4 adapter port 1 at 0b20 (i2c-4)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: Radeon i2c bit bus 0x90 (i2c-5)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: Radeon i2c bit bus 0x91 (i2c-6)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: Radeon i2c bit bus 0x92 (i2c-7)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: Radeon i2c bit bus 0x93 (i2c-8)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: Radeon i2c bit bus 0x94 (i2c-9)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: Radeon i2c bit bus 0x95 (i2c-10)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 

Next adapter: card0-VGA-1 (i2c-11)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 


Now follows a summary of the probes I have just done.
Just press ENTER to continue: 

Driver `it87':
  * ISA bus, address 0x228
    Chip `ITE IT8620E Super IO Sensors' (confidence: 9)

Driver `k10temp' (autoloaded):
  * Chip `AMD Family 15h thermal sensors' (confidence: 9)

Driver `fam15h_power' (autoloaded):
  * Chip `AMD Family 15h power sensors' (confidence: 9)

To load everything that is needed, add this to /etc/modules:
#----cut here----
# Chip drivers
it87
#----cut here----
If you have some drivers built into your kernel, the list above will
contain too many modules. Skip the appropriate ones!

Do you want to add these lines automatically to /etc/modules? (yes/NO)

Unloading cpuid... OK
```

I ran sensors -f and got this:

```
andy@7 ~/Downloads> sensors -f
fam15h_power-pci-00c4
Adapter: PCI adapter
power1:           N/A  (crit =  65.19 W)

radeon-pci-0008
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +41.0°F  (crit = +248.0°F, hyst = +194.0°F)

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +39.6°F  (high = +158.0°F)
                       (crit = +176.0°F, hyst = +174.2°F)

it8620-isa-0228
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:           1.03 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +3.06 V)
in1:           1.54 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +3.06 V)
in2:           2.02 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +3.06 V)
in3:           2.05 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +3.06 V)
in4:           2.04 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +3.06 V)
in5:           2.23 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +3.06 V)
in6:           2.23 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +3.06 V)
3VSB:          3.34 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +6.12 V)
Vbat:          3.17 V  
fan1:        1730 RPM  (min =   10 RPM)
fan2:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan3:         556 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan4:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan5:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
temp1:        +93.2°F  (low  = +260.6°F, high = +260.6°F)  sensor = thermistor
temp2:       -198.4°F  (low  = +260.6°F, high = +260.6°F)  sensor = disabled
temp3:        +64.4°F  (low  = +32.0°F, high = +140.0°F)  sensor = Intel PECI
temp4:       +109.4°F  
temp5:       +113.0°F  
temp6:       +113.0°F  
intrusion0:  ALARM
```

Comment: Try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1253722/how-to-display-fan-speeds). It works for Asus motherboards, I do not know if it works for Gigabyte motherboards.

Comment: @Doug Smythies E: Package 'hddtemp' has no installation candidate and psensors does not show fan speeds.

Comment: You are asking 2 different questions. `hddtemp` is just what it sounds like, HDD (Hard Disk Drive) Temp.  That is different than `sensors` which gives you CPU and motherboard temps and fan speeds.  They are unrelated tools.  Please update the question with just one question.

Comment: As far as the original question regarding `sensors`, run `sensors-detect` again, this time pay attention to the output, especially the Super IO section..in fact post the Super IO section here.

Comment: @rtaft I edited my question.

Comment: looks good now, I see it8620-isa-0228 in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Try these commands to install **hddtemp**:

   ```
   wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/h/hddtemp/hddtemp_0.3-beta15-53_amd64.deb  
   mv hddtemp_0.3-beta15-53_amd64.deb /tmp
   cd /tmp
   sudo apt install ./hddtemp_0.3-beta15-53_amd64.deb
   ```
2. For **sensors**, first load the kernel driver that can read drive temperatures using the following command:

   ```
   sudo modprobe drivetemp
   ```

Then run these commands:

```
   sudo sensors-detect
   sensors
```

Answer (score 1):

In 20.04, `hddtemp` is in the universe repository. Check to make sure that has been added to your system.

```
$ apt policy hddtemp
hddtemp:
  Installed: 0.3-beta15-53
  Candidate: 0.3-beta15-53
  Version table:
 *** 0.3-beta15-53 500
        500 [local mirror]/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Add it here:

[image]

Comment: How do I add it to community-maintained free...?

Comment: Just tick the box

Comment: It was already ticked.

Comment: Something's messed up in your packaging system then. More info needed.

Comment: I have added a lot of material to my original post. And Linux Geanie provided the answer.